# Computational science in the FAQ

Tags: discussion, scope, software-questions

One area that I've noticed that is missing from our FAQ is an item about computational physics, and use of computers in doing physics research. So far we've been taking the view that general questions about computing are off topic here and should be sent to SO or SU, but that there are certain computing-related questions that [would be on topic](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43/should-we-allow-computational-questions). I'd like to add something to the FAQ to reflect that. Can anyone suggest a good wording that, as clearly as possible, delineates what kinds of computation-related questions we will accept?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact those topics do not fit too well on any current SE -- on SO there is a little place for science, on Physics/Stats/Maths is too little place for programming, for TCS this is waaay to trivial and SU is rather for how-to-turn-my-computer-ON questions.

That's why there is an [Area proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/28815/computational-science), currently half-way in commitment. Since it is quite likely it will get to beta within few months, I think we should just wait -- those Qs are not making enough harm to be in rush.

Comment: Yeah, I'm committed to that proposal, but a few months is not that short, and even afterwards I would like to have something to put in the FAQ about computational questions - perhaps just pointing people to the computational science site, once it goes public.