# Is Minecraft On-Topic?

Tags: support, scope

Long question short: Changing Minecraft's Gravity via Code: StackOverflow, Math, Physics, or SciFi&Fantasy?

### Actual Question:

#### Premise:

So, some quick background on the question I want to answer. The Minecraft world is generally depicted as a large cube (which, of course, doesn't make physical sense anyway, concentration of mass and all that), but, assuming it is a cube, I want to write a modification that employs accurate gravity. It does not need to be a perfect model, Newtonian is fine, furthermore, I have to apply force vectors **as well as** cancel out minecraft's preexisting gravity, which is [a bit odd](http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Entity#Motion_of_entities).

#### Conundrum:

So, as you can see, I'm quite split. I am writing **code** to implement **physics**, using **math** in a **fantasy** world. So, what site do I use? I get the feeling it would be on topic here, since I am trying to be accurate to real-world physics, but then is the question of how to cancel the preexisting gravity also on-topic? I don't have any specific difficulties with the code, as I'm fairly well-versed, so I assume stack overflow is a no go, furthermore, there are too many other parts to my question for it to fit on math, and I see nothing in SciFi&Fantasy's on-topic guidelines that match this question, so that only leaves physic, but the on-topic page for physics specifically states that made-up physics is off-topic. I, however, want to apply real physics to a made-up world... would that make this on-topic?

Anyway, I just wanted to make sure what I'm asking is allowed... maybe there's another site this would be even more suited for. Regardless, any help is appreciated!

Comment: At the risk of veering a _bit_ off topic in comments here - I play a _lot_ of Minecraft and help run the server that the gaming SE community has been using for the past few years. We tend to put heavily modded packs together to play, if you come up with something, I'm sure we'd be interested in testing :) (I'm also the director of community management for SE/SO).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

None of the above. Physics simulations in videogames belong on the [Game Development SE](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/). They even have a tag, [physics-engine](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/physics-engine), for this exact purpose.

Answer (score 1):

[The gory details of coding physics simulations are off-topic, even though the details of the physics to be simulated are on-topic.](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5623/520)

Also you left [Computational Science (sometimes called "scicomp" after their URL)](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/) off your list of possible sites. If you know enough about the foundation of numeric modeling that might be the site on which to seek truly expert help to refine a implementation. However, I'm not clear on how interested they are in hearing from someone with no experience in numerical work trying to get a first project off the ground.

Answer (score 1):

Minecraft is not on topic because, in short, it's a fantasy world which is not generally studied by physicists.

However, if you can transform your question into one that asks about "real physics", then it could be fine. But you should follow the advice in our [homework policy](/q/714) (even though this is not homework; it's generally good advice): specifically, you should set up the problem yourself, make an attempt to solve it, and when you ask your question, ask about the specific step that you get stuck on. You can ask for help formulating your question in the [chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71/the-b-har).